# How to make filter gridview using select2 tag only run after press enter

Tags: search, gridview, filter, yii2, jquery-select2

Here's my view coding for the gridview :

```
<?php Pjax::begin(); ?>
<?= GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
    'filterModel'=>$searchModel,
    'showPageSummary'=>true,
    'pjax'=>true,
    'striped'=>true,
    'hover'=>true,
    'responsiveWrap' => false,
    'columns'=>[
        [
            'attribute' => 'color',
            'value' => function ($model) {
                return $model->color->name;
            },
            'filterType'=>GridView::FILTER_SELECT2,
            'filter'=>ArrayHelper::map(\app\models\Color::find()->asArray()->all(), 'name', 'name'),
            'filterWidgetOptions'=>[
                'pluginOptions'=>['allowClear'=>true, 'minimuminputLength' => 3],
            ],
            'filterInputOptions'=>['placeholder'=>'Any Color', 'multiple' => true ],
            'group'=>true,  // enable grouping
            'label' => 'Color',
             'headerOptions' =>
                 ['style'=>'max-width: 70%; font-size: 12px;overflow: auto; word-wrap: break-word;'],
            'contentOptions' =>
                ['style'=>'max-width: 70%; font-size: 12px;overflow: auto; word-wrap: break-word;'],
        ],
        // ['class' => 'kartik\grid\ActionColumn','template' => '{update},{view}',],
    ],
]);

?>
<?php Pjax::end() ; ?>
```

this select2 filter is work fine, but i want to make this search not automatically running filter. I mean my code is work but everytime i remove one tag filter it's automatically runnning filter on gridview, and what i want is eventhough i remove one tag it's not running filter after i press enter on my keyboard.

Any one can help me please?
Thank You

Comment: Remove pjax then you good to go. :)

Comment: @InsaneSkull, I've tried to remove pjax, but it doesn't change anything. It still automatically runing filter though i dont press the enter. If I press enter it'll select the first data on the list....